# Blender 3D UVs scale issue appearing after export _FBX_OBJ_COLLADA

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, blend-files, .fbx

I have an issue with UV textures coordinate - exporting some .fbx/ .obj/.collada objects from Blender 2.78c to Kanzi Rightware.

I'm working in a company developing product design and electronics, and I'm making research of what software will be suitable for future OpenGLES production pipeline with Kanzi Rightware.

At that moment I did specific tests and experiments with Blender, 3Ds Max, Maya, Cinema 4D.
I shaped and transformed an object with same operations in each program - subdivided x3, simple booling operation, triangulating, applying scale. rotation. location. (called also freezing -cinema, Maya) and exporting to Kanzi etc.

The program - Blender is looking really suitable to me for the project, I've been using it for years, but the problem it appearing with UV's.

After the export, I import the file (I've tried with .fbx/; .collada/ and .obj) in Kanzi.
Blender's object always looks with different UVs compear to the default of Cinema and Max...?!?

Can you give me an idea what could be wrong with it. Is it UV calculation on export wrong or what?

Basically what I'm doing step by step in each of those program is the following steps:
 1. Create default cube + UV generated
 2. Add subdivision 3 times
 3. Convert/Apply the modifier to mesh
 4. Creating one more Cube - without UV generated
 5. moving the new cube to Z, -1 unit, press enter /Now the cube is aligned
 6. with it's the top part to the center of the grid
 7. Add Booling modifier between the cube and the shaped sphere
 8. Apply Booling Modifier/
 9. Check the UV-s are correct after the operation
 10. Exporting the model via .FBX file

I did experiment with different file formats including .dae, and .obj. The Geometry export is correct but when I import all them in R_Kanzi there are big UV differences.

What should I do? And how this UV scaling could be fixed?
Best Regards

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As I tested UV map for that cube shouldn't be that long by Y axis. Did you try to apply scale via Ctrl+A menu? (generally it shouldn't be other than 1 but to be sure).

Answer (score 1):

Zak! 
Thank you, yes I did that after the boolean operation.

Actually, I found the thing... I opened the programs individually and I saw the process of UV generating in the early beginning - by the default cube. It looks like there is the KEY for my issue.

In each of the programs by default UV layers were generated for the 1st cube in a different configuration. I saw that in 3D's max, and Cinema4D they are equal to reset textures in Blender operation, stretched to the whole UV for each individual face.

[image]

[image]

Thank you! Anywhay!